# Why is *ngFor seemingly looping infinitley?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Can anyone help me understand why this ngFor seemingly gets to the end and then loops again?

**Template**

```
<div class="row">
    <h2>Results</h2>
  </div>
  <div *ngFor="let bson of bsonResults; let i = index">
    {{i}}
    {{getItemContext(bson, i)}}
    <!-- <mat-card class="card collection-card">
      <a [routerLink]="toDetails(results.database, results.collection, bson.data._id.$oid)" data-toggle="tooltip"
      title="Click to visit details page" attr.aria-label="Item Name: {{utility.getItemTitle(bson, results.nameField)}}">{{utility.getItemTitle(bson, results.nameField)}}</a>
      <mat-card-content [innerHTML]="getItemContext(bson)">
        {{getItemContext(bson)}}
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card> -->
  </div>
```

**Relevant methods from .ts file**

```
 getItemContext(bson, i) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(bson);
    if (this.searchCriteria.q !== '') {
      return this.contextWithSearchString(bson);
    } else {
      return this.contextWithoutSearchString(bson);
    }
  }

  contextWithSearchString(bson) {

    let keys = Object.keys(bson.data);
    let longString: string;
    let highlightedText: string;

    for (let key of keys) {
      let bsonItem: string = bson.data[key];
      bsonItem.toString();

      if (typeof bsonItem === 'string') {
        if (bsonItem.toUpperCase().includes(this.searchCriteria.q.toUpperCase())) {

          let indexOfTerm = bsonItem.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.searchCriteria.q.toUpperCase());
          if (bsonItem.length > 100) {
            if (indexOfTerm - 50 <= 0) {
              bsonItem = bsonItem.substring(0, 100) + '...';
            } else {
              bsonItem = '...' + bsonItem.substring(indexOfTerm - 50, indexOfTerm + 50) + '...';
            }
          }

          if (longString === undefined) {
            highlightedText = this.utility.highlight(bsonItem, this.searchCriteria.q);
            longString = '<b>' + key + ': ' + '</b> ' +  highlightedText + ' | ' ;
          } else {
            highlightedText = this.utility.highlight(bsonItem, this.searchCriteria.q);
            longString = longString + '<b>' + key + ': ' + highlightedText + ' | ';
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return longString;
  }

  contextWithoutSearchString(bson) {

    let keys = Object.keys(bson.data);
    let longString: string;
    let i = 0;
    keys.forEach(key => {
      // only return strings in search context, and only return the first 4.
      if (typeof (bson.data[key]) === 'string' && i < 4) {

        let dataValue: string = bson.data[key];
        if (dataValue.length > 100) {
          dataValue = dataValue.substring(1, 100) + '...';
        }

        if (longString === undefined) {
          longString = '<b>' + key + ': </b>' + ' ' + dataValue  + ' | ';
        } else {
          longString = longString  + '<b>' + key + ': </b> '  + dataValue  + ' | ';
          i++;
        }
      }
    });
    // if the item only contains objects (no strings) then just return 600 chars of the raw JSON.
    if (longString === undefined) { return JSON.stringify(bson.data).substring(0, 600); } else {
      return longString;
    }

  }
```

**and here's how it looks on the page** (..looks fine)
[image: html displayed]

**yet here is my console getting bombarded**

[image: console]

Strangely enough the page is displaying the output from the getItemContext function on the page the correct amount of times. However, I put a console log at the start of the function to log my bson objects and this is continually filling up the console with objects. I stuck an index variable in to see if the count looked right and it does (bsonResults contains a 11 items). When the console has gotten up to logging out the 11th item it just starts again.

Comment: The functions in your template (HTML) get called *every time change detection fires*, which is a lot.

Comment: Is this something I need to concern myself with then? It does not appear to be affecting performance. I originally encountered the problem because I was trying to diagnose a problem in one of those methods using a log - and I couldn't make any sense of it because it was logging too often

Comment: You should avoid calling functions from the template. Think about using getters or pipes.

Comment: Doesn’t a getter have the same issue? A pure pipe seems to be the only solution..

Comment: `A pure pipe seems to be the only solution` -> not true. You could use the `locationStrategy.onPush` and you will then "tell" angular when trigger the render. Hence no "random" change detection fired.

Comment: I used a pipe and that's done the trick, thanks guys